# Early 90s Mac freeware anti-virus program

Tags: history, anti-virus

I'm trying to find information about a popular early 90s Macintosh freeware anti-virus program. I can't remember its name.
As I recall it installed as an extension and the icon was a frilly black 'V' on a white background. I believe development stopped in the mid-90s in response to the threat of Word macro viruses.

Thanks

Comment: [Virex](https://books.google.com/books?id=AToEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT31&lpg=PT31&dq=HJC+Software+virex&source=bl&ots=kaGUf4NFtU&sig=BvfNCbeLcQiRfz5MLsNyLjp1lqg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nFZrVeLRN7OxsASb9oCAAQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=HJC%20Software%20virex&f=false), perhaps? I can't find a frilly black V icon, though.

Comment: Wow… early 90's all I can remember is Norton - we weren't so worried back then. We also thought Alta Vista was going to be the search engine of the future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disinfectant** was a popular freeware antivirus program on the Mac [from the 80's until its official retirement at version 3.7.1 in 1998](http://www.norstad.org/disinfectant-retire.txt):

> Announcement and Press Release May 6, 1998 
>   Updated: October 11, 1998
>   I regret to announce that I am officially retiring Disinfectant, our free
>   anti-viral utility for the Macintosh. The current version 3.7.1 is the last
>   version. Disinfectant will not be updated for the new Autostart 9805 worm or for
>   any future viruses, worms, or other Macintosh malware.

It's the last antivirus I've used on my Macs. There hasn't been much need.

Comment: That's it! The icon is a frilly V, but with a no symbol over it. Thanks for this bit of nostalgia